# Draw Text on Bitmap in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, fragment, paint

I want to add text on imageview , so I followed this blog [drawing multiline text on bitmap using canvas](https://www.skoumal.com/en/android-drawing-multiline-text-on-bitmap/#:%7E:text=%20Android%20-%20drawing%20multiline%20text%20on%20bitmap,matrix...%203%20Complete%20source%20code.%20%20More%20)
But when I run the activity the text is not shown on image and the activity is terminated abruptly. I am doubtful that something is wrong in drawmultilinetext() method but unable to recognize.

public class WallpaperTabFragment extends Fragment {

```
@Nullable

 private GridView gridview;
Uri imageUri;
ImageView userQuotePic;

String compose_text;
private static final int  PICK_IMAGE = 100;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_tab, container, false);
    userQuotePic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_quote_pic);
    //taking text from previous activity
    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    compose_text = extras.getString("string");

   // imageUri = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(userQuotePic.toString()));
    gridview  = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    Bitmap bitmap = imageView2Bitmap(userQuotePic);
    final ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(position ==0){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Choose from gallery",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                openGallery();
                Bitmap bitmap = imageView2Bitmap(userQuotePic);
                //get URI from bitmap
                imageUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),bitmap);

            }
           else{
                userQuotePic .setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
                Bitmap bitmap = imageView2Bitmap(userQuotePic);
                //get URI from bitmap
                imageUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),bitmap);

            }
         if(imageUri!=null){
             Toast.makeText(getContext(), "imageuri is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Bitmap drawtext = drawMultilineTextToBitmap(WallpaperTabFragment.this,(int)id,compose_text);
             if(drawtext !=null){
                 userQuotePic.setImageBitmap(drawtext);
                 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             else{
                 Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Something wrong in bitmap",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }


         }
         else{
             Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ImageUri is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

           // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
              //  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
                // Pass image index
              //  i.putExtra("id", position);
                //startActivity(i);
        }

        private Uri getImageUri(Context applicationContext, Bitmap bitmap) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), bitmap, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png", "drawing");
            return Uri.parse(path);
        }


    });
    return view;

}

private void openGallery() {

        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery,PICK_IMAGE);
    }
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        imageUri = data.getData();

        userQuotePic.setImageURI(imageUri);


    }
}
private Bitmap imageView2Bitmap(ImageView view){
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    return bitmap;
}
public Bitmap drawMultilineTextToBitmap(WallpaperTabFragment gContext,
                                        int gResId,
                                        String gText) {

    // prepare canvas
    Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);


    // set default bitmap config if none
    if(bitmap.getConfig() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // resource bitmaps are imutable,
    // so we need to convert it to mutable one
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    // new antialiased Paint
    TextPaint paint=new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    // text color - #3D3D3D
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 61, 61));
    // text size in pixels
    paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));
    // text shadow
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

    // set text width to canvas width minus 16dp padding
    int textWidth = canvas.getWidth() - (int) (16 * scale);

    // init StaticLayout for text
    StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(
            gText, paint, textWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

    // get height of multiline text
    int textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();

    // get position of text's top left corner
    float x = (bitmap.getWidth() - textWidth)/2;
    float y = (bitmap.getHeight() - textHeight)/2;

    // draw text to the Canvas center
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(x, y);
    textLayout.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    return bitmap;
}
```

}

Here I am attaching the error shown in logcat

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: If your app crashes you can find the exception in the logcat. Then you see what goes wrong.

Comment: The `gResId` in `drawMultilineTextToBitmap` needs to refer to a resource in your app, but its not as you are passing adapter id casted to int there.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh the error was due to id which I passed in DrawMultilineText() method, I have changed the id to imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position] and it worked .